# Meromorphic function with poles of unbounded order

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Let:

$$
f(z) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z - j)^{j}}
$$

so that $f$ has a pole of order $j$ at $z = j$ for each integer $j > 0$. Is $f$ meromorphic in the extended complex plane? It is analytic except on a discrete set of poles, so I think the answer is "yes," but $f$ isn't a rational function, and I know that every function that is meromorphic on the extended complex plane is rational.

Am I misunderstanding the definitions here?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, edited.

Comment: At $\infty,$ the positive integers are not discrete.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Maybe I am getting the terminology wrong here. My understanding is that the important thing is for the poles to not contain a convergent sequence $(z_n)$, since then we could look at $\frac{1}{f}$ and argue that $f = 0$ for any region that contains $(z_n)$. Clearly $f \neq 0$ here so I don't see how that argument applies.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: $\{j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a convergent sequence on the _extended_ complex plane: it converges to $\infty$.  Did you mean merely meromorphic on the _entire_ complex plane?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see. I am worried about the following: call $\Omega$ the region constructed by removing all of the points where $\frac{1}{f}$ is not analytic. Then $\frac{1}{f(j)} = 0$ for all $j \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, so $f$ is identically 0 in $\Omega$, since it $= 0$ on a set with an accumulation point in $\Omega$, contradiction. I think the problem is that we had to remove $\infty$ from $\Omega$, right? So $\{j\}$ doesn't converge in any set where $\frac{1}{f}$ is analytic.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see why my worry is addressed, but I'm still not clear why this function fails to be meromorphic on the extended complex plane. Is there an essential singularity at $\infty$? Or is the pole at $\infty$ not isolated?

Comment: Infinity is not an isolated singularity for $f$; it's actually not that hard to show that $f$ sends any neighborhood of infinity surjectively to the complex plane (and infinity at the poles in the neighborhood)

Comment: That's because a "neighborhood" around $\infty$ is just $|z| > R$, right? I am a bit unclear how the usual analysis notions apply to $\infty$. Does it follow that a meromorphic function has at most finitely many poles? Because if they were contained in a disk, they'd have a convergent subsequence and we could conclude that the function is constant, or they're unbounded, so there's a singularity at $\infty$ that's not isolated?